# How to convert epoch seconds to normal time in perl?

Tags: perl, date

I have a string of epoch seconds "1510652305" which when i convert to normal time on unix command line using

```
`date -d @1510652305`
```

i get
Tue Nov 14 15:08:25 IST 2017

But when i tried it in perl using something like this

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;
use Time::localtime;

$kickoff_time=1510652305;
$kickoff_time=ctime($kickoff_time);
```

i get

Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970

How can i achieve the result i am getting in linux in perl?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't overthink it!

```
my $kickoff_time = localtime 1510652305;
say $kickoff_time; # Tue Nov 14 15:08:25 2017
```

If you absolutely, positively need the timezone in there:

```
use POSIX qw{strftime};

my $kickoff_time = strftime '%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', localtime 1510652305;
say $kickoff_time; # Tue Nov 14 15:08:25 IST 2017
```

Note that this is locale-dependent.

Comment: We have to use localtime to convert in time from epoch seconds and gmtime to convert in time from normal seconds i got it now....Thanks!!

Comment: Still confused. Both `localtime` and `gmtime` expect the input to be epoch seconds.

Comment: Exactly. To expound, `localtime()` takes the epoch and returns a string (or date parts array) representing the time in your local timezone; `gmtime()` takes the epoch and returns a string (or date parts array) representing the time in UTC.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `Time::Piece` for this job - it's core in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 
use Time::Piece;

my $t = localtime ( 1510652305 );

print $t;
```

It'll print default format, or you can use formatted using `strftime`.

Comment: I don't know where you're from, and if that's convenient for you, but are you going to be at the London Perl Workshop the weekend after next?

Comment: I'm oxford based. I hadn't realised there was one. I might have a look and see if can get there, but odds  aren't that great ;)

Comment: I meant to include a link... [here it is](act.yapc.eu/lpw2017/). The LPW is a yearly event, always at the end of the year, on a Saturday, for free, in a university building in relatively central London. Attendance varies somewhere between 100 to 200 people, with usually three or four tracks of talks in parallel, and a visit to the pub afterwards. I've been there once before, and going (and speaking) this year. A few other regulars like Dave Cross will be there, too. I didn't even know you're from England tbh. I'm going from Berlin, so Oxford should not be that hard. ;)

Comment: OP is not accessing date parts, so Time::Piece doesn't help with anything here. The scalar value returned by Time::Piece::localtime() is no different than the scalar value returned by the built-in `localtime()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The funny thing is: this script prints a formatted time for me, but`perl -Mstrict -MTime::Piece -wle 'print localtime (1510652305)'` prints `253810141011723170`. I have to use `$ perl -Mstrict -MTime::Piece -wle 'print localtime (1510652305)->strftime`.